# PhpStorm 2019.2: Material UI components requiring props which are not required

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, phpstorm, material-ui

PhpStorm 2019.2 is informing me, that `Button` component from Material UI need to have `href` prop added, because it is required. But I see something else in [Material UI API](https://material-ui.com/api/button/).

Here is screenshot:

[image]

And here's the code:

```
<Button
  color="primary"
  variant="contained"
  disabled={this.state.loading}
  type="submit"
>
  Add
</Button>
```

Similar things is happening to me with, for example, `Grid` or `FormControl` components. According to PhpStorm, those should have `component` prop defined. And again, Material UI specs says something else.

[image]

I'm using `"@material-ui/core": "^4.3.0"` and `"typescript": "^3.5.2"`.

With what is something wrong? Is it bug in PhpStorm or in Typescript?

Comment: There must be something wrong with PhpStorm, since I a using your setup (material-ui + typescript) and my Button does not need a href prop. I am working with vscode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the IDE, please follow [WEB-40515](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-40515) for updates